# Unity3d, baked shadows quality

Tags: unity-game-engine, light, shadows

- UPDATE: the problem was in floor size. I just made it smaller and problem is solved.

Hello there, I spent almost 1 week already googling... hope that you can help me with that. I baked my shadows, result and all needed settings are shown on the picture. The problem is that quality of shadow on the tree is much much better than of shadow on the ground. Do you have any guesses why?

I just made this one tree bigger than others so that it's easy to see the problem...

(shadow quality is set as the highest, rendering path is Deffered lightning)

[image]

Comment: Couldn't it be because the `Differed lighting` and tree->tree shadow receiver is closer and tree->ground shadow receiver is far.

Comment: @Dinal24 tried with Forward rendering, absolutely same result. (changed it in the camera and in the player settings)

Comment: What happens when you make your ground object smaller? If this improves things maybe you should increase the importance of the ground in light-map.

Comment: @tea when I made the tree smaller, the shadow on the ground became so small and transparent that it's almost now visible, lol. however the shadow on the tree is still same quality. and yeah, it's all static shadows because when I remove the light they stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing the size of the ground object solved the issue.

The likely reason this works is that texel budget per object is limited by the lightmap size regardless of user-defined texels per unit. For example, if lightmaps are 2048x2048 and the ground is 2x2 km, there is ~1 pixel per square meter, assuming 1 unit is 1 meter.

Although it was not the case here, inconsistencies between shadows may be observed when dynamic and static shadows use inconsistent resolutions.

Comment: didn't you see, the resolution was 1000 texels?  I tried just now with 100000 texels, same picture. didn't understand your second paragraph. no, all shadows are static because if I remove the light they stay. @tea

Comment: @DealWithMeal I was suggesting you make the ground smaller, not the tree. 100000 should be capped to something smaller. So, the idea was that if you have a very large ground object you need to spread your texel budget so shadow quality will be lower. Aside, not sure whether this one is a great question for stack overflow, you can get in touch with me (eelstork) on unity forums and I'll consider having a look at your file which is probably the faster way to fix this. If we find that this can be re-formatted as a less idiosyncratic question we can always come back here later and update.

Comment: hey, you are genius ;D the floor size was the actual problem :))

Comment: @DealWithMeal - updating my answer now that we know what the problem was.